# bind form validation in other components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have components in order to add user.

This is my form component:

```
createForm(): void {
    this.courseAddForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        name: ['', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.maxLength(this.val.maxLen.title)
        ]],
        roleId: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
}
```

`name :` username ,

`roleId :` selected role from dropdown .

I create a acomponents for `roleId` . `<kt-searchable-dropdown>`

**HTML :**

```
       <form id="courseAddForm" [formGroup]="courseAddForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="form-group kt-form__group row">
                    <!-- title -->
                    <div class="col-lg-6 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile">
                        <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid" appearance="outline">
                            <mat-label>{{'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate}} *</mat-label>
                            <input matInput formControlName="title" [placeholder]="'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate">
                            <!--requied error-->
                            <mat-error *ngIf="courseAddForm.get('title').errors?.required">
                                {{ 'VALIDATION.REQUIRED.TITLE' | translate }}</mat-error>
                            <!--length error-->
                            <mat-error *ngIf="courseAddForm.get('title').errors?.maxlength">
                                {{'VALIDATION.MAX_LENGTH' | translate}} {{val.maxLen.title}}
                            </mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile">
                        <kt-searchable-dropdown [formGroup]="courseAddForm" [formcontrolName]="'courseId'" (selectedId)="selectedCourse($event)"
                            [formTitle]="'COURSE.COURSE_GROUP'" [url]="url"></kt-searchable-dropdown>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
```

This is my component for `roleId` dropdown :

**TS :**

```
export class SearchableDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() url: string;
@Input() formTitle: string;
@Input() ItemId: number;
@Input() formcontrolName: string;
@Input() formGroup: FormGroup;
@Output() selectedId = new EventEmitter<number>();

loading = false;
values: KeyValue[];
title: string;
fC: FormControl;

constructor(
    private searchService: SearchableDropDownService,
    private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {

}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getValues(null);
}

getValues(event): void {

    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    this.loading = true;

    let model = {} as SendDateModel;
    model.page = 1;
    model.pageSize = 60;
    model.title = event;

    this.searchService.getAll(this.url, model).subscribe(data => {
        this.values = data['result']['records'];
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        this.loading = false;
    });

}
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>{{formTitle| translate}} *</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="courseId" >
        <div class="col-lg-12 mt-4 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile">
            <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid" appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>{{'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate}} *</mat-label>
                <input (keyup)="getValues($event.target.value)" matInput
                    [placeholder]="'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="loading" class="mb-2" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
        <mat-option  (click)="emitdata(item.key)" *ngFor="let item of values"
            [(ngModel)]="ItemId" [value]="item.key">
            {{item.value}}
        </mat-option>
        <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('courseId').errors?.required">
            {{ 'COURSE.VALIDATIONS.REQUIRED.CLASS_LEVEL' | translate }}</mat-error>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I write this code but it is not work.

**i need to bind validation in the form in this components . for example when `roleId` is required and user not select item ,show error that the `roleId` is reqierd , I need to show it in this components `SearchableDropdownComponent` . how can i do this ????**

Comment: Please put these on stackblitz as it will be helpful for us to solve.

Comment: Validators.required it's ok if the value is not null, so, in your "options" you need included a `<mat-option  [ngValue]="null">Choose one</mat-option>`. BTW, use simple `formControlName="courseId" ` see the case sensitive and not []. Futhermore, you can pass to the input the own formControl if you want, and use `[formControl]="control"` where `@Input()control:FormControl` and `<kt-searchable-dropdown [control]="formGroup.get('courseId')"..>`

Comment: i need when dropdown is `touched` and not select any this i show error

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using angular `observables`. Create a service to hold the error state in your first component.

ErrorService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorService {

  private errorObj = new Subject<any>({});
  data = this.errorObj.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  updatedErrorObj(error){
    this.errorObj.next(error);
  }

  getErrorObj(){
    return this.errorObj.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Inside your first component, you need to create an instance of this service and on error stage update the error object.

FirstComponent.ts

```
// Creating an instance of service in constructor
constructor(private errorService: ErrorService) { }
onSubmit() {
    if(this.courseAddForm.invalid) {
        // Updating error object
        cont errorObject = { key: 'value' }; //Create your custom error object here
        this.errorService.updatedErrorObj(errorObject);

    }
}
```

Caputure this error in the `SearchableDropdownComponent`

```
// Creating an instance of service in constructor
constructor(private errorService: ErrorService) {
    errorService.getErrorObj.subscribe(data => {
      // do what ever needs doing when data changes
      // You will recive the error object here.
    })
}
```

Please refer this [blog](https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb#7758) for details.